# how to send TCP packet to a server under Ionic or Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am building an ionic app for android and ios phones. I would like to ask if there is a method we can use to send TCP packet to server? Any plug in or module support this?

I do not want http or httpClient modules, just want to send TCP packet.

Comment: not sure if you are looking for websocket module. if that`s the case try using npm install ws --save. once you are done installing try following the normal steps of using websocket connection. probably that would help.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?